# War getting Err404 by Tomcat7 but if it is run on eclipse everything is ok

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, war

I am getting an Error 404 when I try to run an Eclipse's Dynamic Web Project that I deployed in Tomcat7.

The thing the puzzles me is that **if I run the project in Eclipse**, which uses the same Tomcat server, **it carries out the xhtml page correctly**.

I exported the project as a war and retained the web.xml as it was created by Eclipse.
I started the Tomcat server and I deployed the war with "War file deploy" option of Tomcat's manager. Deployment ended positively but still the app doesn't start, neithet by clicking on the corresponding link in the Tomcat manager nor by copying the url in a new browser page.

My O.S is Ubuntu 17.04.
Tomcat7 came along with the IDE Ecplipse installation.
In the project I also used IceFaces.

For sure I created a simpler Dynamic Web Project containing only a classic "Hello wordl" xhtml page; the behaviour is the same: when run on Eclipse it is ok, when exported, deployed in Tomcat e run by clicking on its link in the manager page I get the 404 error.

I have already read other similar posts but I couldn't find any solution working for me.

My web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://        java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>IceTest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Please note I also tried to change

```
<param-value>client</param-value>
```

with

```
<param-value>server</param-value>
```

Maybe has someone of you a hint about this problem?
I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I have found where the problem was.

My html page has a different name from the ones listed in my web.xml . 
I thought welcome-file-list is an optional tag. It is indeed if the html page has been named index.html (the Tomcat default) but if it differs then welcome-file-list must be defined.

I leave this answer because it can be useful for other guys with the same doubt as mine.